# How to stop ReSharper removing spaces in object initializer

Tags: c#, formatting, resharper

I like my object initializers to look like this:

```
new Point { Label = g.Key.Name, Claims = g };
```

When hit the semicolon key, they get reformatted like this:

```
new Point {Label = g.Key.Name, Claims = g};
```

Where is the option to stop my padding from being removed?

Comment: I don't care which way mine look, but StyleCop punches me in the teeth if they don't look the first way. **Hates StyleCop**

Comment: This also worked for the removing spaces R# adds after casting. This was causing a lot of churn in code files where R# code cleanup and VS Reformat Document were being used.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

For R# 7, I can get this to vary by going to<sup>1</sup>

> ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Spaces

and toggling

> Other | Within single-line initializer braces

the example for which is

```
int[] x = new int[] {0, 1, 2};
```

versus

```
int[] x = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
```

Although the example is of array initialization, it also appears to control object initialization.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>In R# 5, "Code Editing" was "Languages".</sub>

Comment: Thanks freakin god, this was driving me insane.. resharper kept removing spaces from my CSS formatting..
Edit: nvm cant find the right option

Comment: Seems this option has been moved from 'Other' to 'Around Braces'

Comment: Seems this option has been renamed: `Spaces | Around braces | Within single-line expression braces`

Or add it directly to the .DotSettings file: `<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/SPACE_WITHIN_SINGLE_LINE_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_BRACES/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using an [`.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org/) file, you can control this behaviour by adding:

```
space_within_single_line_array_initializer_braces = true
```

See also
[the official resharper documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/EditorConfig_CSHARP_SpacesPageSchema.html#resharper_csharp_space_within_single_line_array_initializer_braces) on supported .editorconfig entries. These typically let you customize everything you could customize from the formatting styles menu for all of Jetbrains' IDEs.