# Spaces in brace formatting in Resharper

Tags: c#, resharper

Our coding standard at work requires the following array initialisations to have spaces in them:

```
int[] arr1 = { 1 };
int[] arr2 = { 2, 3 };
```

However, Resharper's auto-format is removing the spaces. I've looked in the locations recommended by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747351/custom-brace-formatting-with-resharper) but they are all about multi-line array declarations. Does anyone know if Resharper offers this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it might have already been answered in this SO answer: [How to stop ReSharper removing spaces in object initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280361/how-to-stop-resharper-removing-spaces-in-object-initializer)

The key word here is that you are using an initializer.