# How to stop ReSharper removing spaces after css properties

Tags: css, resharper, space

I've tried every option in the resharper options menu. Still cant stop it from removing my space..

What im trying to achieve:

```
#main.campaign.showings_aside .showings_title { padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px; }
```

What resharper keeps doing when you make the last semi colon:

```
#main.campaign.showings_aside .showings_title { padding-left: 30px;padding-bottom: 30px; }
```

referer [How to stop ReSharper removing spaces in object initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280361/how-to-stop-resharper-removing-spaces-in-object-initializer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so after pulling out my hair I finally found the answer if anyone else is interested.

Here's where the options is located (in visual studio):

> Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> CSS -> Formatting Style -> Code Layout -> Properties [Single ine formatting]